# If a textbox is already full how to tell the textbox to enter the data in the next textbox that is empty

Tags: vb.net

I have textbox1.text as the main textbox. Any text that is input into textbox1.text when the submit button is selected is supposed to input the text into the next available textbox which is textbox2.text, textbox3.text and textbox4.text. How can I tell vb.net that if textbox2.text is full then input the text into textbox3.text and if textbox3.text is full to input the text into textbox4.text. Here is where I got stuck. I'm still in the process of learning more about vb.net.

```
Private Sub SubBttn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubBttn.Click
        If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
            If TextBox2.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
                TextBox3.Text = TextBox1.Text
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More compact code to do the job

```
Private Sub btnsubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsubmit.Click

Dim LstTextBox As New List(Of TextBox) 'A list to contain text boxes excluding the main text box

LstTextBox.Add(TextBox2)
LstTextBox.Add(TextBox3)
LstTextBox.Add(TextBox4)

For Each Tbox As TextBox In LstTextBox

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Tbox.Text) = True Then 'If text box is empty or contains white spaces

        Tbox.Text = TextBox1.Text 'Copies text from main text box
        TextBox1.Clear() 'Clears main text box
        Exit Sub

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I didn't realize how many different ways this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the textbox's textlength with the textbox's max length, and if they match up, the next

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If TextBox1.TextLength = TextBox1.MaxLength - 1 Then
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

This will switch focus to textbox2 as soon as the last digit is typed.

If you want it in a button event, then do the same as above, but without the `- 1`

If you want to keep the text the same throughout, then do this:

```
Private Sub SubBttn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubBttn.Click
    If TextBox1.TextLength = TextBox1.MaxLength Then
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

You would repeat the same action for each textbox, for example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.TextLength = TextBox1.MaxLength Then
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
            TextBox2.Focus()
        End If
        If TextBox2.TextLength = TextBox2.MaxLength Then
            TextBox3.Text = TextBox2.Text
            TextBox3.Focus()
        End If
        If TextBox3.TextLength = TextBox3.MaxLength Then
            TextBox4.Text = TextBox3.Text
            TextBox4.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I'm trying the last step that you've provided me with but when I click on the submit button nothing happens. I'm not sure why the text is not transferring to textbox2 or textbox3. Please help.

Comment: Glad you got it to work! A crucial step to learning is to try and experiment with things yourself, to attempt these problems yourself. Once again, glad I could help!